# Check if a number is non zero using bitwise operators in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Check whether a number `x` is nonzero using the legal operators except `!`.

Examples: `isNonZero(3) = 1`, `isNonZero(0) = 0`

Legal ops: `~` `&` `^` `|` `+` `<<` `>>`

- Note : Only bitwise operators should be used. `if`, `else`, `for`, etc. cannot be used.
- Edit1 : No. of operators should not exceed 10.
- Edit2 : Consider size of `int` to be 4 bytes.

```
int isNonZero(int x) {
return ???;
}
```

Using `!` this would be trivial , but how do we do it without using `!` ?

Comment: In C a non-zero number is non-zero. You haven't explicitly required the function to return 1 or 0 (but it is implied). Please _explicitly_ define what your function will return. All you've given are 2 examples.

Comment: At least make the function return a bool to avoid answers like `return x;` (yes, I did it). A bit of context would also be interesting, why would you (anyone) need to write such a function with such constraints ?

Comment: Since when is `+` a bitwise operator?

Comment: do people really ask lame questions like this in interviews? Its total BS (excuse the use of overly technical jargon)

Comment: @Oli: Because it uses every single bit of its operands! It's bitwise, but byte foolish.

Comment: The correct answer to this interview question is: What do you intend to do with the result? comparison? So why can't I do the comparison in the first place? I have better things to do with my time, you have failed to be selected to become my boss.

Comment: I have the same question and the reason for all the odd constraints is that it's a homework problem for a Computer Systems class, trying to help us understand the intricacies of C bit-twiddling ...

Comment: Should `-x` be a legal operation since it's equivalent to `~x + 1`, similarly `y - x = y + -x`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The logarithmic version of the adamk function:

```
int isNotZero(unsigned int n){
  n |= n >> 16;
  n |= n >> 8;
  n |= n >> 4;
  n |= n >> 2;
  n |= n >> 1;
  return n & 1;
};
```

And the fastest one, but in assembly:

```
xor eax, eax
sub eax, n  // carry would be set if the number was not 0
xor eax, eax
adc eax, 0  // eax was 0, and if we had carry, it will became 1
```

Something similar to assembly version can be written in C, you just have to play with the sign bit and with some differences.

EDIT: here is the fastest version I can think of in C:

1) for negative numbers: if the sign bit is set, the number is not 0.

2) for positive: `0 - n` will be negaive, and can be checked as in case 1. I don't see the `-` in the list of the legal operations, so we'll use `~n + 1` instead.

What we get:

```
int isNotZero(unsigned int n){ // unsigned is safer for bit operations
   return ((n | (~n + 1)) >> 31) & 1;
}
```

Comment: Damn you I was going to post the same (except for the assembly part) :P +1 for THE solution

Comment: You are using 11 bitwise operators here. (5x|, 5x>>, 1x&).

Comment: "sub" isn't a bitwise op; a C++ solution would be easier if we \'re allowed `-1`

Comment: Why don't you just use neg? xor eax, eax; neg ecx; adc eax, 0;

Comment: @wj32 Yeah, this should work. I completely forgot which instructions affects CF.

Comment: isNotZero explaination... n and -n can both only be non negative numbers IF n = 0.  (n | (~n + 1)) is essnetially "or"ing n with -n.  You then shift the most significant bit (which is the sign bit) to the right by 31 to put it in the least significant bit position.  Then chop off any sign extended ones by "and"ing with 1.

Comment: There's a shorter assembler solution that doesn't modify the input variable (which is often better): xor eax, eax; cmp eax, n; adc eax, 0;

Comment: The ASM in the question is actually broken: `xor`-zeroing clears CF.  Clear one or two registers first, then use `sub` or `cmp` / `setc`.  (Or `adc` if you think that's any more acceptable than `setc`: both are clearly using the result of an unsigned comparison as an integer for you, unlike the `+` operator the OP specified.  Maybe if you cast to a wider type and shift the high bit down to the bottom...  You could do that in asm to justify using `adc` (implementing 64-bit add in 32-bit mode), or just use 64-bit code.

Answer (score 11):

```
int isNonZero(unsigned x) {
    return ~( ~x & ( x + ~0 ) ) >> 31;
}
```

Assuming int is 32 bits (/* EDIT: this part no longer applies as I changed the parameter type to unsigned */ and that signed shifts behave exactly like unsigned ones).

Comment: I guess this assumes 2nd complement representation (x + ~0 == x-1)

Comment: On my Intel 32-bit Linux machine this function returns `0` or `-1`. If you subtract the answer from zero you would have a working function (on Intel 32-bit with gcc).

Comment: @PP: That is why I wrote "Assuming ... signed shifts behave exactly like unsigned ones". This shows that on Intel 32-bit with gcc they don't behave the same, which is perfectly OK. In fact there are more problems with this solution when `x` is of signed type. I shall elaborate about that shortly...

Comment: I changed the parameter type to unsigned not only because results of bitwise operations on signed types are implementation-defined when arguments have negative values, but also because adding and subtracting a non-zero constant cannot reliably be used either, as then there'll be at least one value of x with which `+` or `-` will result in overflow, and hence undefined behavior.

Answer (score 11):

Why make things complicated ?

```
int isNonZero(int x) {
    return x;
}
```

It works because the C convention is that every non zero value means true, as isNonZero return an int that's legal.

Some people argued, the isNonZero() function should return 1 for input 3 as showed in the example.

If you are using C++ it's still as easy as before:

```
int isNonZero(int x) {
    return (bool)x;
}
```

Now the function return 1 if you provide 3.

OK, it does not work with C that miss a proper boolean type.

Now, if you suppose ints are 32 bits and + is allowed:

```
int isNonZero(int x) {
    return ((x|(x+0x7FFFFFFF))>>31)&1;
}
```

On some architectures you may even avoid the final `&1`, just by casting x to unsigned (which has a null runtime cost), but that is Undefined Behavior, hence implementation dependant (depends if the target architecture uses signed or logical shift right).

```
int isNonZero(int x) {
    return ((unsigned)(x|(x+0x7FFFFFFF)))>>31;
}
```

Comment: because that's not the requirement. the requirement is to return 1 for non-zero

Comment: @Matt Ellen: let the OP write it would you ? When he wrote his question he stated `Example: isNonZero(3) = 1`, and example is not a requirement, never have been.

Comment: Ok, but your function doesn't fulfil the example either.

Answer (score 2):

```
int is_32bit_zero( int x ) {
    return 1 ^ (unsigned) ( x + ~0 & ~x ) >> 31;
}
```

1. Subtract 1. (`~0` generates minus one on a two's complement machine. This is an assumption.)
2. Select only flipped bit that flipped to one.
3. Most significant bit only flips as a result of subtracting one if `x` is zero.
4. Move most-significant bit to least-significant bit.

I count six operators. I could use `0xFFFFFFFF` for five. The cast to `unsigned` doesn't count on a two's complement machine ;v) .

http://ideone.com/Omobw

Comment: This will return 0 when x = 0x80000000

Comment: also + and - are not allowed, if you allow them it's much more simple.

Comment: @kriss: `+` is explicitly allowed, see list.

Comment: @Matt: No, that is why there is a cast to `unsigned`. See ideone link.

Comment: @usta: Yep, didn't think of that. Fortunately the fix is easy - use AND NOT instead of XOR.

Comment: @MSalters: Unary minus isn't though… eliminated it, although if I assume 32-bit two's complement I could just do `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: sorry, I didn't spot that before.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yep, that's essentially what I did. Now our solutions are very similar (use the same idea), yet not completely identical :)

Comment: You can do 2's complement math using `unsigned` in C, because 2's complement + and - are the same binary operations as plain base2.  (Unlike for 1's complement or sign/magnitude).  i.e. use `unsigned x`, and `x + ~0U`, and your function will run the same on all C implementations (except for hard-coding `>>31`).

Comment: Tested for all `i` from INT_MIN to INT_MAX on x86.  https://godbolt.org/g/NAEi9N.   `is_32bit_zero(x) == !!x` for all possible `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise OR all bits in the number:

```
int isByteNonZero(int x) {
    return ((x >> 7) & 1) |
           ((x >> 6) & 1) |
           ((x >> 5) & 1) |
           ((x >> 4) & 1) |
           ((x >> 3) & 1) |
           ((x >> 2) & 1) |
           ((x >> 1) & 1) |
           ((x >> 0) & 1);
}

int isNonZero(int x) {
  return isByteNonZero( x >> 24 & 0xff ) |
         isByteNonZero( x >> 16 & 0xff ) |
         isByteNonZero( x >> 8  & 0xff ) |
         isByteNonZero( x       & 0xff );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if creating a second function counts as a bitwise operator :)

Comment: I'm not a C person and I'm wondering why `return x|(x&0);` wouldn't work? Put that in your answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: @Spencer Ruport: No, that won't work. That's a trivial identity; it will just return x. The result must be either 1 or 0.

Comment: You are using 34 bitwise operators here. (11x|, 11x>>, 12x&). Well, 33 I guess, the last '|' results in a syntax error.

Comment: @JoshD: Why should the result be 1 or 0, in C every non zero values means true. The identity works perfectly :-) Try is in an if if you don't believe so.

Comment: @kriss: Yes, you're correct, but the question asks to return an integer with value either 0 or 1 as you can see from the function in the question. Otherwise you'd just return x and it would be a trivial problem.

Comment: this isn't what the OP expects because the number of operations have exceed 10

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to or the bits.  For instance, if you know your number is 8 bits wide:

```
int isNonZero(uint8_t x)
{
    int res = 0;
    res |= (x >> 0) & 1;
    res |= (x >> 1) & 1;
    res |= (x >> 2) & 1;
    res |= (x >> 3) & 1;
    res |= (x >> 4) & 1;
    res |= (x >> 5) & 1;
    res |= (x >> 6) & 1;
    res |= (x >> 7) & 1;

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I think you have `<<` where you mean to have `>>`

Comment: You are using 24 bitwise operators here.

Comment: @haylem: When I wrote the answer, that wasn't one of the requirements

Answer (score -1):

My solution is the following,

```
int isNonZero(int n)
{
    return ~(n == 0) + 2;
}
```

Comment: `==` is not included in the list of legal operators.

Answer (score -1):

My solution in C.  No comparison operator.  Doesn't work with 0x80000000.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_non_zero(int n) {
    n &= 0x7FFFFFFF;
    n *= 1;
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", is_non_zero(0));
    printf("%d\n", is_non_zero(1));
    printf("%d\n", is_non_zero(-1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `is_non_zero(-1)` returns `2147483647 = 0x7FFFFFFF` (on a system with 32-bit 2's complement `int` like x86: https://godbolt.org/g/DJFTNu).  `n *= 1;` is a no-op (note that it doesn't even appear in the asm output, `is_non_zero` just returns the low 31 bits).  i.e. this doesn't produce a 0 / 1 return value at all.

Answer (score -2):

My solution,though not quite related to your question

> int isSign(int x)

```
{
//return 1 if positive,0 if zero,-1 if negative
return (x > 0) - ((x & 0x80000000)==0x80000000)
}
```

Comment: Comparison operators are not allowed as per the question; Only bitwise operators.

Answer (score -3):

This function will return `x` if it is non-zero, otherwise it will return `0`.

```
int isNonZero(int x)
{
    return (x);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
if(x)
     printf("non zero")
else
     printf("zero")
```

Answer (score -3):

The following function example should work for you.

```
bool isNonZero(int x)
{
    return (x | 0);
}
```

Comment: Just make sure bool is recognized as a type. On Linux using gcc, I had to add these to my .c file: Just make sure bool is defined as a type. Else I did this using gcc on Linux, so bool would be recognized as a type.

    #define true 1
    #define false 0
    typedef char bool;

Comment: "| 0" is completely useless. All the work here is being done by the conversion to bool, if you're using a language with a real bool type, and not a typedef to an integer type.

Answer (score -4):

int isNonZero(int x)

{

```
if (  x & 0xffffffff)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

}

Let assume  Int is 4 byte.

It will return 1 if value is non zero

if value is zero then it will return 0.

Comment: `if` statements aren't allowed in the problem.

Answer (score -4):

return ((val & 0xFFFFFFFF) == 0 ?  0:1);

Comment: That's still an `if`, just in shorthand! Besides, `val & 0xFFFFFFFF == val`.