# Performing a logical not ! using only bitwise operations

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit, logical-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a number is non zero using bitwise operators in C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912112/check-if-a-number-is-non-zero-using-bitwise-operators-in-c)

Hello everyone,

I am working on a project and I need a little help with a function. We need to write a function that performs the logical not, !, using only the following bitwise operators:

```
~ & ^ | + << >>
```

I'm not even sure where to begin.

Comment: @GWW Either that, or a very strange lead developer. :)

Comment: In the description I stated that it's a project. :)

Comment: Yes but a project could mean a homework project :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912112/check-if-a-number-is-non-zero-using-bitwise-operators-in-c

Comment: What project specification would explicitly require you to re-implement a logical operator?!

Answer (score 3):

If you can assume that `true = 1` and `false = 0`, then this might do the trick:

```
bool
not(bool x) {
    bool not_x = x ^ true;
    return not_x;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Logical not returns 0, if value is not zero, 1 otherwise. Assuming 32-bit int:

```
int not_func(int v) {
    /* compress value to single bit */
    int p = (v >> 16) | v;
    p = (p >> 8) | p;
    p = (p >> 4) | p;
    p = (p >> 2) | p;
    p = (p >> 1) | p;

    p ^= 1;
    return (p & 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think to start you want you'll want to clarify the question.  It sounds like you're wanting at a function that will return 0 if any of the bits in a word are "1", and something other than 0 if all the bits are zero.  Assuming a 32bit word "a" you could do something like:

```
na1 = ~a;
shifted_na1 = na1 >> 1;
na2 = shifted_na1 & na1; /* any sequence of zeros is now 2 bits long */
shifted_na2 = na2 >> 2;
na3 = shifted_na2 & na2; /* any sequence of zeros is now 4 bits long */
shifted_na3 = na3 >> 4;
na4 = shifted_na3 & na3; /* any sequence of zeros is now 8 bits long */
shifted_na4 = na4 >> 8;
na5 = shifted_na4 & na4; /* any sequence of zeros is now 16 bits long */
shifted_na5 = na5 >> 16;
final = shifted_na5 & na5; /* any sequence of zeros is now 32 bits long */
really_final = final & 1;
```

Comment: logical ! should return 1, not 0xffffffff for 0 argument.

Comment: right, I had another error as well.