# Remove extra whitespace from a string in C

Tags: c, algorithm, whitespace

I have this string

```
"go    for    goa"
```

and the output should be

```
"go for goa"
```

I want to remove the extra spaces. That means two or more consecutive spaces should be replaced with one space. I want to do it using an in place algorithm.

Below is the code I tried but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* Function to remove spaces in an string array */
char *removeSpaces(char *str) {
  int  ip_ind = 1;
  /* In place removal of duplicate spaces*/
  while(*(str + ip_ind)) {
    if ((*(str + ip_ind) == *(str + ip_ind - 1)) && (*(str + ip_ind)==' ')) {
      *(str_ip_ind-1)= *(str + ip_ind);
    }
    ip_ind++;
  }
  /* After above step add end of string*/
  *(str + ip_ind) = '\0';
  return str;
}
/* Driver program to test removeSpaces */
int main() {
  char str[] = "go   for  go";
  printf("%s", removeSpaces(str));
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Most solutions seem needlessly complicated:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void strip_extra_spaces(char* str) {
  int i, x;
  for(i=x=0; str[i]; ++i)
    if(!isspace(str[i]) || (i > 0 && !isspace(str[i-1])))
      str[x++] = str[i];
  str[x] = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char str[] = "  If  you  gaze   into  the abyss,    the   abyss gazes also   into you.    ";
  strip_extra_spaces(str);
  printf("%s\n",str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava, I fixed it

Comment: Great solution.

Comment: Old, but still great! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I can't even tell what your function is trying to do. For one thing, the first time through, that -1 will access before the start of the string. Try something like:

```
char *removeSpaces(char *str) {
    char *inp = str, *outp = str;
    int prevSpace = 0;

    while (*inp) {
        if (isspace(*inp)) {
            if (!prevSpace) {
                *outp++ = ' ';
                prevSpace = 1;
            }
        } else {
            *outp++ = *inp;
            prevSpace = 0;
        }
        ++inp;
    }
    *outp = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Comment: No it wont, because he initialized ip_ind as 1.

Answer (score 1):

You aren''t checking for a space.. You are checking for a tab. Replace \t with (I mean space..)

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition doesn't work. I will show you my code. It is similar to yours, by just using two pointers: `back` and `front`.

If `front` is not a space, or `front` is a space but `back` is not a space, you need to copy `front` to `back+1`.

```
char *removeSpaces(char *str)
{
    if (*str == '\0') return str;

    char *back = str;
    char *front = str + 1;
    /* In place removal of duplicate spaces*/
    while(*front != '\0')
    {
        if (*front != ' ' || *back != ' ')    // highlight
            *(++back) = *front;
        front++;
    }

    /* After above step add end of string*/
    *(back + 1) = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Would tell best answer left space @end ? Here simple translation to JS:

```js
function strip_extra_spaces(str) {
  var i, x;
  for (i = x = 0; str[i]; ++i)
    if (!isspace(str[i]) || (i > 0 && !isspace(str[i - 1])))
      str[x++] = str[i];
  str[x] = '\0';
  return str;
}

str = "  If  you  gaze   into  the abyss,    the   abyss gazes also   into you.    ";
console.log(
  strip_extra_spaces(str.split(""))
  .join("")
  .replace(/\0.+/g, "")
  .replace(/\s/g, '☐')
)

function isspace(c) {
  return c == ' ';
}
```

Looking for something similar in C# to compare multiple strings and made this - inspired by recursion.ninja's and similar C# answer to [Efficient way to remove ALL whitespace from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219454/efficient-way-to-remove-all-whitespace-from-string/37368176#37368176) - also problematic - removed spaces completely.

```
public static string TrimAllWithInplaceCharArray(string a) {
    var len = a.Length;
    var srcA = a.ToCharArray();
    int dstIdxA = 0;
    int planSpace = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        var ch = srcA[i];
        switch (ch) {
            case '\u0020': case '\u00A0': case '\u1680': case '\u2000': case '\u2001':
            case '\u2002': case '\u2003': case '\u2004': case '\u2005': case '\u2006':
            case '\u2007': case '\u2008': case '\u2009': case '\u200A': case '\u202F':
            case '\u205F': case '\u3000': case '\u2028': case '\u2029': case '\u0009':
            case '\u000A': case '\u000B': case '\u000C': case '\u000D': case '\u0085':
                if (planSpace == 1) planSpace = 2;
                break;

            default:
                if (planSpace > 1)
                {
                    srcA[dstIdxA++] = ' ';
                }
                srcA[dstIdxA++] = ch;
                planSpace = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    return new string(srcA, 0, dstIdxA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

1. You are **tracking the '\t' tab, but you have to remove the
   spaces.**
2. Also, you are tracking and finding the '\t', **but you have no steps to removing it (I added one).**
3. Every-time you mustn't increment the `ip_ind`, you must inc, only when deletion is not done, because when deletion is done, that
   scenario will be equal to incremented.
4. Your scenario will fail for `""`, to avoid it, add a check parameter as below (Method 1) or else start from `ip_ind` from 0 as in (Method 2). (Thanks to  @Lee Daniel Crocker)

**Solution:**

You could try like this.,

**Method 1 : ip_ind starts from one.**

```
/* Function to remove spaces in an string array */
char *removeSpaces(char *str)
{
  int  ip_ind = 1;
  char *ptr;

  if(*str)
    return str;

  /* In place removal of duplicate spaces*/
  while(*(str + ip_ind))
  {
    if ( (*(str + ip_ind) == *(str + ip_ind - 1)) && (*(str + ip_ind)==' ') )
    {
        ptr = str + ip_ind;
        //Functionality for removal of spaces.
        do{
           *(ptr-1) = *ptr;
        }while(*ptr++ != '\0');


    }
    else //Inc only if deletion is not done.
    ip_ind++;
  }

 /* After above step add end of string*/
  *(str + ip_ind) = '\0';

 return str;
}
```

**Method 2 : ip_ind starts from zero.**

```
char *removeSpaces(char *str)
{
  int  ip_ind = 0;
  char *ptr;
  /* In place removal of duplicate spaces*/
  while(*(str + ip_ind))
  {
    if ( (*(str + ip_ind) == *(str + ip_ind + 1)) && (*(str + ip_ind)==' ') )
    {
        ptr = str + ip_ind+1;

        do{
           *(ptr-1) = *ptr;
        }while(*ptr++ != '\0');


    }
    else
    ip_ind++;
  }

 /* After above step add end of string*/
  *(str + ip_ind) = '\0';

 return str;
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to solve this without using that additional pointer ptr?

Comment: @krrishna No it is not because, your pointing the current position you need `ip_ind`., for traversing to the end you need atleast one variable. In this case it is `ptr`

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* Function to remove spaces in an string array */
char *removeSpaces(char *str) {
  int  ip_ind = 0;
  while (*(str+ip_ind) != 0) {
    if (*(str + ip_ind++) == 32) {
      if (*(str + ip_ind) == 32) {
        int x=ip_ind;
        while (*(str + x +1) != 0) {
          *(str + x)= *(str + 1 + x++);
        }
        *(str + x)= 0;
        --ip_ind;
      }
    }
  }
  return str;
}
/* Driver program to test removeSpaces */
int main() {
  char str[] = "go   for  go";
  printf("%s\n", str);
  printf("%s\n", removeSpaces(str));
  char str2[] = "go     for  go for go";
  printf("%s\n", str2);
  printf("%s\n", removeSpaces(str2));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
dda$ ./a.out
go   for  go
go for go
go     for  go for go
go for go for go
dda$
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple one** for You

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char a[100];
int i,t,k;
scanf("%[^\n]s",a);
t=strlen(a);
for(i=0;i<t;)
{
    if((a[i]==' ')&&(a[i+1]==' '))
    {
        for(k=i+1;k<t;k++)
        {
            a[k]=a[k+1];
        }
        t=t-1;
    }
    else
        i++;
}
printf("%s",a);
return 0;
}
```