# Return identical spaces between words using C#

Tags: c#, string

How can i make sure the spaces between words in a sentence are identical, using C#?

Example

```
What are     you looking for
```

should be

```
what are you looking for
```

Kind regards

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"\s{2,}", " ");` to replace each *two or more whitespaces* match into a *single space*

Comment: Please update your spec. It is not clear if you still need to take care about words in the sentence, the capitals and so on.

Comment: `string str = string.Join(" ", "What are     you looking for ".ToLower().Split(' ').Where(s => s != ""));`

Comment: @SeM-ՍեՄ - see also [StringSplitOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) - `string str = string.Join(" ", "What are you looking for ".Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));`

Comment: @SeM-ՍեՄ - but it seems your way is a few ns faster than using `StringSplitOptions`. On the other hand, from the ways discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442421/c-sharp-fastest-way-to-remove-extra-white-spaces I don't know if I implemented the `StringBuilder` way correctly, but using a compiled(!) Regex was about twice as fast as your way. (My `StringBuilder` implementation took about 1.3 times the time of the compiled Regex; which would be vastly different from the observations in that question; but they probably didn't use a *compiled* Regex). Tested with BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: @Corak yeap, as said [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442421/c-sharp-fastest-way-to-remove-extra-white-spaces#comment7563505_6442477) from _duplicate answer_ .